# How to kill from above

Tags: assassins-creed-rogue

I just got Assassins Creed: Rogue on Steam, and I am stuck on Hope's lesson. I can complete it except for the "attack from above" part. How am I supposed to do that? Whenever I try to jump and attack, either nothing happens (timed wrong or something), or I land, then attack.
Thanks!

Comment: Go to a ledge or something above the target. Then kill...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple, to perform attack from above you have to be on some height(such as roof), as soon as target is under you

> press the x button (do not jump)

on xbox controller (square on ps) or attack button(or you can keep mashing x button and the action will be performed when target is in your range).

p.s.:

> press B button for tackle from above

Comment: Thanks, should've looked at the controls more thoroughly...

Comment: Happy to help..